# Atmosphere in spaceships

Tags: gravity

I was wondering what would happen if you open a window on a spaceship with artificial gravity (not talking about centrifuge gravity - genuine artificial gravity) of 1g? Would the atmosphere decompress or would the artificial gravity hold the atmosphere inside the ship?

Comment: What is "genuine artificial gravity"? Do you have any thoughts on this yourself?

Comment: I'm referring to actual real gravity. I know this gets into the realm of fiction however I'm still puzzled with the question if a ship would decompress if it is equipped with artificial gravity.

Comment: Would [worldbuilding.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

The motion of individual gas particles (gas molecules) is extremely fast, so the ship would decompress without any significant difference from if the "gravity" force was not present.

There's an example of calculation of gas molecule speed here:

http://www.physicspages.com/2015/07/01/ideal-gas-relation-of-average-speed-of-molecules-to-temperature/

Answer (score 1):

If your spaceship is in space I think we can safely assume that there is a vacuum on the other side of your spaceship window. Therefore the atmosphere will escape through the open window at an RMS velocity of 500 ms<sup>-1</sup>.

The time taken for the entire atmosphere in the ship to escape is a function of its volume and the area of the open window.

The gravity, artificial or real doesn't matter one whit, will have a negligible effect on the time taken for decompression to be complete.

The pressure inside a regular Earth-based party balloon is less than 10% more than atmospheric pressure so the pressure differential is less than 0.1 atm and does it really matter which way up you hold the balloon if you were to release the pressure? Does gravity matter in this instance?

Comment: Good argument in the last paragraph.

Comment: Great argument. I agree I was totally off (won't try to explain my argument any more, I was trying to construct an artificial earth)

Comment: Well, if the spaceship in question was toroidal, with an outer radius of, say, 400km and an inner radius of 300km, rotating about its central axis (like a big fat tyre) once every 15 minutes or so, then that would generate a g-force of about 10 ms^-2 on the inner surface of the "ship".  The "roof" of the ship, 100km "up" is the same distance from the "floor" as is "space" from the Earth's surface. The dynamics are different, our artificial gravity is only 75%g at the roof, and on Earth g at 100 km is still pretty much g, but it might be safe to open a window.  Why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

I think he means why wouldnt the air continue to push towards the source of gravity like it does on earth as opposed to shooting away from the ship because the air doesnt shoot off the earth even though it is by a vacuum too.

I think the answer is that the air would eventually go towards the gravity after decompression but the pressure would be much lower because there is not miles of air pushing down on the gravity source like there is on earth.